# Error when using $addToSet and $each, Mongo and Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use $addToSet to add a array of Strings to a MongoDB.

The Object setup is as defined:

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', {
    License: { type: String, index: true },
    "Classifications": [
        {
            Classification: { type: String, _id: false }
        }
    ]
});
```

The current object looks like this in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55b03f9337b46f10d38843d7"
    },
    "Classifications": [
        "A - GENERAL ENGINEERING CONTRACTOR",
        "B - GENERAL BUILDING CONTRACTOR",
        "C12 - EARTHWORK AND PAVING"
    ],
    "License": "CA_*****"
}
```

I am trying to run $addToSet on the following array:

```
var classifications = [ 'B - GENERAL BUILDING CONTRACTOR',
  'C10 - ELECTRICAL',
  'C33 - PAINTING AND DECORATING',
  'C29 - MASONRY',
  'C-9 - DRYWALL',
  'C54 - TILE (CERAMIC AND MOSAIC)',
  'C-5 - FRAMING AND ROUGH CARPENTRY',
  'C20 - WARM-AIR HEATING, VENTILATING AND AIR-CONDITIONING',
  'C36 - PLUMBING',
  'C39 - ROOFING' ]

Company.update({ '_id': company._id }, { $addToSet: { "Classifications": { $each: classifications } } }
```

When I run Company.update in Node, I am getting the error

> [TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in C39 -
>   ROOFING]

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out my issue.

In the Schema I had:

```
"Classifications": [
        {
            Classification: { type: String, _id: false }
        }
    ]
```

Which was looking for a object with a String in it. The Schema should of just been:

```
"Classifications": [String]
```

Which allows for

```
Company.update({ '_id': company._id }, { $addToSet: { "Classifications": { $each: classifications } } }
```

to run and add the strings from the array with no issue